# Rellenar array de valores únicos y sumar valor

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo un rango con dos columnas (codigo y cantidad) y necesito almacenar en un array valores únicos (códigos) y sumar su cantidad si el código aparece más veces en el rango.

Por ejemplo si el código 3552 tiene en la fila 1 del rango un valor de 3000 y en la fila 50 del rango tiene el valor de 5000 necesito que en el array aparezca una sola vez el código 3552 y el valor 8000.

Podéis echarme una mano?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Dónde almacenas ese rango inicial? Muéstranos el código y lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Es un rango dinámico, definido por la última fila y última columna. No tengo nada definido porque realmente no sé hacerlo.

Mi rango está formado así:

Set rangodatos = ws.Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(ufila,ucolumna))

Sé como rellenar un array desde ese rango, pero lo que no sé es  sumar los valores si están ya incluidos. He visto algún ejemplo utilizando diccionarios, pero tampoco son exactamente como necesito.

Podría hacer la ñapa de utilizar una hoja auxiliar pero me gustaría hacerlo lo más elegante posible...

Gracias.

Comment: Un diccionario es lo que necesitas. Porque decis que no te sirvio? al tener un solo indice unico, si el codigo figura en el diccionario, sumas a su contenido. Si no existe, lo agregas.

Comment: Creo @dogwall que si se tiene un arreglo con los códigos sin repetición: `cod=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]` y la `Columna A` contiene los códigos con repetición `_Arg1_=[40,20,10,20,50,....]`y la `Columna B` contiene los datos `_Arg3_=[113,476,343,388,514,...]` existe un método [WorksheetFunction. sumar.Si](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.sumif) que permite hacer lo que buscas, sólo que  en este caso, cada elemento en `cod`, se tiene que trabajar en un bucle: `For Each _Arg2_ In cod... Next _Arg2_` esto creo que podría ser un inicio para lograr lo que quieres.

Comment: @gbianchi dije que no me servía porque no he utilizado nunca diccionarios y no tengo claro como usarlos. El ejemplo que estuve probando sólo conseguía almacenar la key y extraerla, pero no sé como añadir a esa key un valor (sumando el anterior si existe) y luego extraer todo, tanto key como valor.



HubertRonald, lo que comentas lo había también pensado pero no sé cuanto penalizará el utilizar el bucle. Son muchas las filas de datos a evaluar, casi 300.000 por fichero, y me da miedo que el proceso se lleve mucho tiempo. No obstante lo probaré.

Gracias a ambos.

Comment: Lo más elegante, si tus datos son tal cual mencionas, sería resumirlos con una tabla dinámica, y sumar valores. De ese modo, la tabla dinámica haría exactamente lo que dices en tu ejemplo (i el código 3552 tiene en la fila 1 del rango un valor de 3000 y en la fila 50 del rango tiene el valor de 5000 necesito que en el array aparezca una sola vez el código 3552 y el valor 8000). Prueba a resumir tus datos con tablas dinámicas y nos cuentas.

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes la tabla dinámica ya la había contemplado, el problema es que esos datos y la tabla dinámica no sería el formato final. Es decir, esa suma de valores la utilizaré para otras operaciones y montar una tabla dinámica en medio me parece más engorroso. Sobre todo teniendo en cuenta que esa tabla no será mostrada en el fichero, sería un paso intermedio que tendría que ocultar o eliminar una vez realice las operaciones que necesito. 
Gracias.

Comment: Sí, pero si te creas la tabla dinámica, ya tendrías el array de valores únicos y su suma, que es lo que buscas. Luego te llevas la tabla dinámica a un array y borras la tabla dinámica y continúas con tu proceso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto debería servirte si tu propósito es meter los valores en un array, podrías jugar directamente con el diccionario, pero deberías aprender a utilizarlos. En ese caso, obvia a partir del dimensionamiento del `arrFinal`

```
Option Explicit
Sub ValoresUnicos()

    Dim arrDatos, arrFinal, DictUnicos As Scripting.Dictionary, i As Long, Key

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Set DictUnicos = New Scripting.Dictionary 'Para que esto funcione necesitas la referencia Microsoft Scripting Runtime

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NombreDeTuHoja")
        arrDatos = .UsedRange.Value 'esto va a coger la hoja entera(hasta donde haya datos) y la pondrá en un array
    End With

    For i = 2 To UBound(arrDatos) 'asumiendo que en la primera fila hay encabezados
        If Not DictUnicos.Exists(arrDatos(i, 1)) Then 'asumiendo que la ID está en la columna A
            DictUnicos.Add arrDatos(i, 1), arrDatos(i, 2) 'almacenamos la ID como Key y su valor como item (Columna B)
        Else
            DictUnicos(arrDatos(i, 1)) = DictUnicos(arrDatos(i, 1)) + arrDatos(i, 2) 'si ya existe le sumamos los datos nuevos
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim arrFinal(1 To DictUnicos.Count, 1 To 2) 'redimensionamos el array final para que sea igual que las ID únicas
    i = 1 'inicializamos la variable
    For Each Key In DictUnicos.Keys 'recorremos el diccionario para poner sus datos en un array
        arrFinal(i, 1) = Key 'ID
        arrFinal(i, 2) = DictUnicos(Key) 'Su valor
        i = i + 1
    Next Key

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

Yo aprendí a utilizar los diccionarios con esta [guía](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias. Conozco esa guía y gracias a ella ayer pude avanzar bastante. De hecho sólo me faltaba pasar los datos del diccionario al array, que ya veo como se hace, y volcar ese array luego a una hoja vacía.

Comment: Puedes volcar el diccionario directamente a la hoja. `Cells(1, 1).Resize(DictUnicos.Count) = Application.Transpose(DictUnicos.Keys) `y `Cells(1, 2).Resize(DictUnicos.Count) = Application.Transpose(DictUnicos.Items)` no hay necesidad de meterlos en un array. Por otro lado, si te ha servido no olvides marcarla como respuesta para que otros puedan encontrarla fácilmente.

Comment: Ah! pues pensaba que no podía hacerse directamente desde el diccionario... Muy buena solución.
Gracias.